# SQL Server : find members from a number

Tags: sql-server-2012

**Problem :** How to find out from the given number from which numbers this number consists?

> "Sunday = 1", "Monday = 2", "Tuesday = 4", Wednesday = 8", "Thursday =
>   16", "Friday = 32", "Saturday = 64"

**For example :** Given the number 109 this would signify Sunday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Friday, Saturday

Comment: Looks like bad table design. Can you share some more details?

Comment: When you query the table in the field there is a number. This includes information about the days of the week. 
I need to extract the days of the week from this number as a string

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Int2BinaryToWeekDay (@i INT) RETURNS NVARCHAR(2048) AS BEGIN
    RETURN        
        CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @i &    64 ) > 0 THEN 'Saturday,' ELSE ''  END +
        CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @i &    32 ) > 0 THEN 'Friday,' ELSE '' END +
        CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @i &    16 ) > 0 THEN 'Thurday,' ELSE '' END +
        CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @i &     8 ) > 0 THEN 'Wed,'  ELSE '' END +
        CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @i &     4 ) > 0 THEN 'Tuesday,' ELSE ''  END +
        CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @i &     2 ) > 0 THEN 'Monday,' ELSE ''  END +
        CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @i &     1 ) > 0 THEN 'Sunday,' ELSE '' END
END;
GO
```

Now do following thing.

```
 SELECT dbo.Int2BinaryToWeekDay(109)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a binary design. You need to use bitwise & operator to get the desired output.

```
Decimal = Binary

109 = 1101101
001 = 0000001
------&------
      0000001 = 1

109 = 1101101
002 = 0000010
------&------
      0000000 = 0

109 = 1101101
004 = 0000100
------&------
      0000100 = 4
```

SQL Server has [bitwise operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in built. you can utilize bitwise & for this like:

```
DECLARE @InputNum INT = 109

SELECT ISNULL(STUFF(CASE WHEN @InputNum & 1 > 0 THEN ', SUN' ELSE '' END + 
                    CASE WHEN @InputNum & 2 > 0 THEN ', MON' ELSE '' END + 
                    CASE WHEN @InputNum & 4 > 0 THEN ', TUE' ELSE '' END + 
                    CASE WHEN @InputNum & 8 > 0 THEN ', WED' ELSE '' END + 
                    CASE WHEN @InputNum & 16 > 0 THEN ', THU' ELSE '' END + 
                    CASE WHEN @InputNum & 32 > 0 THEN ', FRI' ELSE '' END + 
                    CASE WHEN @InputNum & 64 > 0 THEN ', SAT' ELSE '' END,1,2,''),'')
```

check the MS documentation for more detailed explaination of bitwise operators.